# Using constants inline

Tags: org-mode, r

How to do the following in `org-mode`:

1. define a constant in the beginning of file, and
2. than use it in the text or even compute on it.

Following methods didn't work for me:

**Method 1:**

```
#+CONSTANTS: t=10

The temperature is `$t`, and twice of that is `2*$t`.
```

How to do both of these?

**Method 2:**

```
The temperature is src_R{t=10; 2*t}, and twice of that is scr_R{4*t}.
```

Here value of `t` is defined in the first R code block (`src_R{t=10; 2*t}`), and the second  block (`scr_R{4*t}`) is trying to compute on the definition of `t`. First block is replaced by `20` as expected, but the second block is not even interpreted as an R code. How can these two be connected?

Comment: Debug help: typo in 2nd inline block, `scr_R` should be `src_R`.

Comment: Thanks @Melioratus. That explains why the second block was not interpreted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Try this**

- Define `t` as default header argument with using `:var t=10`

  ```
  #+PROPERTY: header-args:R :var t=10

  The temperature is src_R{2*t}, and twice of that is src_R{4*t}.
  ```

  > **Note:** Fixed typo in second in-line block and removed `t=10;` assignment.

  **Exports as**

  ```
  The temperature is `20', and twice of that is `40'.
  ```

**Hope that helped!**

---

**Tested Using**

> **emacs version:**     GNU Emacs 24.5.1
>   **org-mode version:**               9.0

Comment: Thanks again @Melioratus. This is exactly the kind of solution I was looking for. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You need to set the `:session` header argument. This tells org that all R calculations will take place in the same session. For example:

> #+PROPERTY: header-args:R :session orgR
>
> I set my constant here src_R{t=10; 2*t}.
>
> Write some more text.
>
> And reuse the constant here src_R{t * 4}.

On export, this generates:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think the defined constant can be used in tables, and only there.

```
#+CONSTANTS: t=10

| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 20 |
#+TBLFM: $2=$1*$t
```

However, you can add the header argument `:session` to make your second method working:

```
The temperature is src_R[:session]{t=10; 2*t}, and twice of that is src_R[:session]{4*t}.
```

You could also do a (not so pretty) trick. You could use a named table and assign that to a `:var` header argument:

```
#+name: t
| 10 |
#+TBLFM: $1=$t

The temperature is src_R[:var t=t]{t=10; 2*t}, and twice of that is src_R[:var t=t]{4*t}.
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @theldoria. This is very helpful.